# Job Scheduler in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have created job scheduler in SQL Server 2008 for executing a stored procedure daily at a certain time. But it is not executing my stored procedure. Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you honestly expecting a good answer from the limited information you have provided? It is like saying to a mechanic "My Car doesn't work, can you tell me what's wrong with it?", but not actually taking your car to the garage. A start would be looking at the results of `EXECUTE msdb.dbo.sp_help_job @Job_name = 'Your Job Name'`, and checking to see what the last run outcome was, if the schedule is set up properly etc.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel *yet again* ? There's already the SQL Server Agent that can do *exactly that* - schedule jobs ....